# loop through input and select elements and hide the previous td

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is looping through all the `input` and `select` elements inside a `div` and checking if the value is empty and then hiding it, it is working perfectly:

```
$("#customfields_1 :input").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).hide();
```

but now what I really want is to hide the previous `td`, something like this:

```
$("#customfields_1 :input").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).prev('td').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `.parent('td').hide();` or `.closest('td').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Traverse up to the `td` before using `.prev()`.

```
.closest("td").prev("td").hide();
```

And review the [DOM traversal API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) from jQuery.

Comment: this is absolutely what i need , tnk you